# How to aggregate model instances into one variable in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Inside projects controller I have this:

```
def index
   @projects = Project.all
   @projects.each do |pr|
     @posts = @posts.what_do_i_use_here(pr.posts.all)
   end
   @posts.order('created_at DESC')
end
```

Each project has its posts, now I want to aggregate posts from all projects into one variable, how do I do that ?
Note, this gets posts from last project without any problem:

```
@projects.each do |pr|
  @posts = pr.posts.all
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify - you only get the last project's posts because of the equals sign! If you had `@posts = [] ..... @posts << @posts.what_do_i_use_here(pr.posts.all)` all posts would have been added but you would have had a huge performance hit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're only interested in posts related to projects:

**Posts are related only to projects**

`@posts = Post.order(created_at: :desc)`

**Posts that are related polymorphically**

`@posts = Post.where(posted_type: 'Project').order(created_at: :desc)`

where `posted_type` is the type field for the polymorphic relation

Comment: Ah, so I can get them all directly from Post model. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help 8)